# 500 Error when trying to compare against SQLite3 database values

Tags: python, http, flask, sqlite

I am trying to load the username and password fields from an SQLite database and compare them against the values input by the user for basic HTTP auth (n the cheack_auth function). I can use the retriveUser function to get a user and display it in a template just fine but I cannot seem to use it within the flask application to compare against to see if the user does infact exist.

According to [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlite3/) I should be able to access the items within the returned dbuser as an array but it does not seem to be working. I am new to python so I am probably missing something basic but I am not sure what it could be.

```
q = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    phone TEXT NOT NULL
);
"""

con = sql.connect("database.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(q)

# original code from https://gist.github.com/PolBaladas/07bfcdefb5c1c57cdeb5


def insertUser(username, password, phone):
    con = sql.connect("database.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (username,password,phone) VALUES (?,?,?)", (username,password,phone))
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def retrieveUsers():
    con = sql.connect("database.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT username, password, phone FROM users")
    users = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return users

def retrieveUser(username):
    con = sql.connect("database.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = (?)", [username])
    user = cur.fetchone()
    con.close()
    return user

def check_auth(username, password):
    """This function is called to check if a username /
    password combination is valid.
    """
    dbuser = retrieveUser(username)
    return username == dbuser[0] and password == dbuser[1]

def authenticate():
    """Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth"""
    return Response(
    'Could not verify your access level for that URL.\n'
    'You have to login with proper credentials', 401,
    {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return authenticate()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting from Python? A 500 status is too ambiguous to diagnose.

Comment: I wish I could tell you Allie, this is for a class and is running on a stack with docker, flask and gunicorn. The most debug info I know how to get with my limited docker knowledge is from the docker-compose logs which only display errors that occur during the build process.

Comment: I don't know much at all about `docker`, but try [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/).

Answer (score 0):

Alright I seem to have solved the problem. My browser was caching my old password entries causing the search to return null. The item returning from the retrieve user function will only return as an array if the object is found otherwise it will return null. checking for null like so in the following code solved the issue.

Thanks to Allie Fitter for helping me figure out how to access the docket logs that pointed me in the direction of this issue.

Here is the resulting code for my check_auth method:

```
def check_auth(username, password):
    """This function is called to check if a username /
    password combination is valid.
    """
    dbuser = retrieveUser(username)
    if dbuser is not None:
        return username == dbuser[0] and password == dbuser[1]
    return False
```